# Поиск файла по правам доступа

Tags: c#

Написать консольное приложение, реализующее работу с файлами.
Приложение должно обладать следующей функциональностью:

- Возможность осуществлять поиск файлов и папок по имени, размеру, дате создания, правам доступа.

Проблема возникла с правами доступа:

Предполагается, что пользователь вводит в консоль права доступа по которым необходимо производить поиск. Для каждого файла в каталоге я вызываю метод `GetAccessControl(fileName)`, он возвращает объект класса `FileSecurity`. Но с чем этот объект необходимо сравнивать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо сравнивать не сам объект `FileSecurity`, а его свойства. Например, свойство `AccessRightType` отвечает за права доступа и возвращает значение в формате перечисления `FileSystemRights`.

```
if(fileSequrityObject.AccessRightType==FileSystemRights.Read)
{
    // Делаем что-то
}
```

Подробнее можно почитать на MSDN [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity(v=vs.110).aspx), [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemsecurity.accessrighttype(v=vs.110).aspx) и [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights(v=vs.110).aspx).